# Rails test env: why does it need default_url_options for ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, email-spec

Why does the test environment need default_url_options be set for ActionMailer?

If I don't set it, I'm getting this when executing my specs:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I'm especially wondering because when setting

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
```

then in theory links in emails will lead to localhost:3000, which as far as I know is not where the test server instance really is running? Still, when using `email_spec` gem and clicking on links in emails, they work, because the gem removes the server name and port, so a link typically looks like this:

```
/en/user/confirmation?confirmation_token=QZu3tw17uozhpEfuVWzF
```

So one more time: what do I need to specify the host for if it's removed by `email_spec` gem anyway?

Comment: The exception is thrown while [preparing the URL](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c8bd12cf5a1dc7ebdb1594334b2598d799d4a746/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L63)

Answer (score 1):

You need it because you are generating URLs in your email and ActionMailer needs the `:host` to know how to properly build the URL.  The fact that email_spec removes it later on is irrelevant.

Comment: It's just that I don't find this option in `test.rb` anymore in a newly created Rails 4.2 app, so why do I need to have it set explicitly in my app (which is 4.2, too, but started with 4.1)?